# How to get the listbox item's properties after event "tap"

Tags: c#, wpf, windows-phone-7

I have a custom listbox. Some of the collections's items have fields "name", "text", "image" and "url". Other may have other fields (a use a template selector). So, if item has fields "name", "text", "url" and "image" - it shows in listbox as 2 textblocks and 1 image. When I tap on the image - program must open new window, open webBrowser and go to URL which is in the item's property "url". I understand how to transmit info from one page to other, but I can't understand how to get the "url" from item. I tried

```
    private void Video_Tap(object sender, GestureEventArgs e) // event when tap on the image
    {
        New tmp = ((sender as ListBox).SelectedItem as New); // New - is the type of collection's item
        string vid = tmp.Video.url; // Video has fields "image" and "url"

        string destination = string.Format("/Video_Page.xaml?uri={0}", vid );
        NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri(destination, UriKind.Relative));
    }
```

but sender has an image type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can call [`Parent`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworkelement.parent.aspx) of the Image sender to get its container (or call it multiple times, depending on how your xaml is structured), then look into the container's [`Children`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.panel.children.aspx) to find the textbox you are looking for. For example, maybe you'd want to do something like this (with setting the `Tag` property of the textbox that contains your url in xaml).

```
var grid = (Grid) ((Image) sender).Parent;
foreach (var child in grid.Children)
{
    if (child is TextBox && ((TextBox) child).Tag == "URL")
    {
        return (Textbox) child;
    }
}
```

Or, if you just want an always-available reference to the ListBox, just set its `x:Name = "_MyListbox"` in xaml, and it will become a field of the class.

As a final option, I'm thinking it might just be easier for you to bind to `ListBox.SelectedItem`, so that you always have some property that contains the currently selected `New` item.

Comment: tryed something like `New tmp = ((sender as Image).Parent.` but i cant see any properties of my item, only methods by default

Comment: You have to cast parent to whatever type its parent is (ie, Panel, StackPanel, etc) as the return type of `FrameworkElement.Parent` is a `DependencyObject`.

Comment: Also, I should mention that you should probably be casting via `(Image)sender` instead of using `as`. The reasoning is because of the failure behavior. It will throw a casting exception *right away*, where as `as` will return null if it is not the correct type, which may lead to a `NullReferenceException` somewhere down the line.

Comment: i'm not sure i understand what do you meen( Can you give me a little example?

Comment: i have a listbox, item of the listbox has grid, 2 textblocks and image  in this grid.

Comment: See my edit to my answer. However, my mention of using binding may be your best option, now that I re-read your question and have a better idea of how your code is structured.