# How do I access the property of an item in a ListBox in XAML?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, windows-phone

I have a listbox of "SmartText" items, which are basically link objects with properties for a title, description, and a url. I'm trying to make the Grid panel in the XAML tappable, so that tapping on the whole Grid navigates to the url. How do I do access the URL property so that I can navigate to it?

```
<controls:Pivot VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
                HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
                Margin="0,0,0,0"
                x:Name="PivotRoot"
                Title="{Binding SmartTextStateModel.Title}" 
                SelectionChanged="Pivot_SelectionChanged"
                Background="{StaticResource PhoneBackgroundBrush}">
    <controls:PivotItem Header="{Binding Path=Labels.SmartTextBingHeaderLabel, Source={StaticResource Translations}}" Tag="bingsearch">
        <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding SmartTextStateModel.BingItemResults}">
            <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Grid Tap="SmartTextElement_Tap">
                        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <TextBlock Grid.Row="0" FontSize="40" Text="{Binding Path=Title}" />
                        <TextBlock Grid.Row="1" TextWrapping="Wrap" FontSize="18.667" Foreground="{StaticResource PhoneDisabledBrush}"
                                   TextTrimming="WordEllipsis" MaxHeight="100" Text="{Binding Path=Description}"/>
                        <TextBlock Grid.Row="2" Foreground="{StaticResource PhoneAccentBrush}" Text="{Binding Path=Url}"/>
                    </Grid>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        </ListBox>
    </controls:PivotItem>

    ...

</controls:Pivot>
```

and the class definition

```
public class SmartTextItemModel : BaseModel
{
    private string _title;
    private string _description;
    private string _url;

    /// <summary>
    /// The title of the linked page (Large text)
    /// </summary>
    public string Title
    {
        get { return _title; }
        set
        {
            if (_title != value)
            {
                _title = value;
                NotifyPropertyChanged("Title");
            }
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Description of the page (smaller text)
    /// </summary>
    public string Description
    {
        get { return _description; }
        set
        {
            if (_description != value)
            {
                _description = value;
                NotifyPropertyChanged("Description");
            }
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Url of the page
    /// </summary>
    public string Url
    {
        get { return _url; }
        set
        {
            if (_url != value)
            {
                _url = value;
                NotifyPropertyChanged("Url");
            }
        }
    }

    public SmartTextItemModel(string _t, string _d, string _u)
    {
        this._title = _t;
        this._description = _d;
        this._url = _u;
    }
}
```

Of course the event handler in the .cs file looks like this:

```
private void SmartTextElement_Tap(object sender, System.Windows.Input.GestureEventArgs e)
{
    ... ?
    // Navigate to url...
}
```

Note: This was the closest StackOverflow question to mine: [How to get the listbox item's properties after event "tap"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13779828/how-to-get-the-listbox-items-properties-after-event-tap), but it still didn't help.

Comment: I don't understand your question. You have the URL property in the ViewModel. Just get it from there.

Comment: The sender in the event handler is a Grid panel element. I've tried multiple ways to get to the element's url from the reference to the Grid panel, but nothing's worked. Each item in the listbox is a different SmartText link.

Comment: Does the `Tap` also select the Item in the ListBox, you could just bind to a SelectedItem and use that in your handler

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the `Grid` is inside the `ItemTemplate` of the `ListBox`. That means that the `Grid.DataContext` property is going to be an instance of your `SmartTextItemModel` class:

```
private void SmartTextElement_Tap(object sender, System.Windows.Input.GestureEventArgs e)
{
    var grid = sender as Grid;
    if (grid == null)
        return;

   var item = grid.DataContext as SmartTextItemModel;
   if (item == null)
        return;

   item.// Navigate to url...
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I wasn't aware of the DataContext property. I thought I needed to access the TextBlock child element and then get the Url somehow.